# which one would be better between these two?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I'm trying to get COUNT(*) from board,

But i'm wondering which will be better performance from following codes :

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM board_*** WHERE article_category = " + foo);
```

OR

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM board_*** WHERE article_category = ?");
pstmt.setInt(1 , foo);
ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
```

It's hard to decide..

Comment: Definitely the 2nd one since you're not directly inserting data which could be malicious into your query. But that has more to do with security.

Comment: its not that hard, considering performance and security implication, PreparedStatement is better

Comment: If you have to choose between those two options, there will be very few cases where the first one is considered *better*, maybe even none. Take number 2!

Comment: If you execute this only once, they will both take the same time, but the second one is safer. If you execute this several times with different parameters, the second one will both be safer, and faster. The choice really isn't hard. As soon as you have dynamic parameters, use prepared statements. It's as simple as that. If you want to make this fast, what you should worry about is: do I have an index defined on article_category?

Comment: Thanks! but what if 'foo' is Integer? does it still affects to security implication and performance?

Comment: The second one can be faster because database can cache on SQL parser, it depends on driver and database certainly.

Comment: @LeeJiSoo performance won't change, but security is still important, because one day the category will become a string, and code that was safe will become unsafe. Stay on the safe side, and use a prepared statement when you have dynamic parameters.

Comment: I got it, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always good to use `PreparedStatement`. Because if safer (from sql injection) and in performance wise it is much faster, because when you use bind variable database server itself caches the parameters and improve the query performance.

If you are more interested here a good paper to read

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/performance/designing-applications-for-performa-131870.pdf